# Issue with Normaliser when using Sylow's Theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I am a having trouble with these questions.

1) For $P\leq G$, what is the normaliser $N_G(P)$? For $G=A_5$ and $D \leq G$ of order 10, show that $D\leq N_G(P)$ for some $P \in Syl_5(A_5)$.

2) Use Sylow's Theorem to prove that $|Syl_5(A_5)|=6$ (This part I can do). Why does this mean that $N_{A_5}(P)$ has order ten, for each $P \in Syl_{5}(A_5) $  ?

3) Using all of the above, prove that if $P \in Syl_5(A_5)$ then $N_{A_5}(P)\cong D_{10}$.

I am able to use the following following theorem, but I am a little unsure how to use it in the sense that D isn't strongly defined.

Suppose $H$ and $K$ are given to us by their set of generator (which is how subgroups are typically represented). Say, $H=\langle X \rangle$ and $K= \langle Y \rangle$. Now suppose that K is finite, If $y^x \in K$ for every $x\in X$ and $y \in Y$ then $H \leq N_G(K)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: Putting $\;Syl_p(G)=\;$ the set of all Sylow $\;p\,-$ subgroups of $\;G\;$ , and $\;n_p:=|Syl_p(G)|\;$ , we have that:

Let $\;P_5\in Syl_5(A_5)\;$ , then$\;n_5=[A_5:N_{A_5}(P_5)]=6\;\text{(why?)}\implies |N_{A_5}(P_5)|=10\;$ . Since for *any* subgroup $\;H\;$ of *any* group $\;G\;$ we have that $\;H\le N_G(H)\;$ , the claim follows... and, in fact, you already have all three.

Comment: I am unsure about how you have worked the subgroup D of order 10 into this proof?

Comment: @CatherineDrysdale That's how one gets $\;n_p\;$ in Sylow's theorems: this number equals the index of any Sylow $\;p\,-$ subgroup's normalizer.

Comment: okay! I get the first two parts. Can you give me any indication about how to show the last part explicitly in terms of their being an isomorphism between them? x

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how they suggest "using all the above" to prove that $\;N\cong D_{10}\;$ , but there are only two groups of order $\;10\;$ up to isomorphism: the dihedral one and the cyclic one. If you can prove $\;N\;$ is not abelian we're done...